# How to use a graph as a function to get an output?

Tags: matlab, function, graph, simulink

I need to get an output Y from an input X based upon a graphical relationship between X-Y. How could I achieve it in my simulink model?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 1D lookup table to approximate the function you want to use. Please see the simulink documentation for details.

Comment: This is how I'd do this too.

Comment: Thanks so much.But the 1-D lookup table is only accepting monotonically increasing data. However my function values are not monotonically increasing. How could it be resolved? Could you please help?

Comment: Perhaps you can split up your curve into several separate 1-D lookup tables, each representing a monotonically increasing portion of your curve, and have logic to select which table to use. Hopefully that will work.